# After installation Adobe phonegap is not working (Windows)

Tags: windows, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, phonegap-cli, phonegap-desktop-app

First Of all when I tried to install it using win32 installer [Official doc](http://docs.phonegap.com/getting-started/1-install-phonegap/desktop/#win) , it hangs the installation process when CLI installation part comes in the process. Seeing that I switched over to the zip installer and run phonegap.exe this came up [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rheyy.jpg) and sticks to this.

How to solve this?

Comment: did you find solution? I've the same problrm

Comment: yeah..I solved it..see the answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved the problem like this:

First of all uninstall the previously installed Phonegap completely, then turn off your windows defender and firewall both. Now reinstall the same again. And it should work!

Hope this helps.